# Scope not updating UI inside the success function of http.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-scope

I want to integrate the same high chart as in [this link](http://www.highcharts.com/blog/194-using-highcharts-with-angular-js) with Restful API using the `$http.get`, it doesn't work because of the `$scope.pieData` is in the success function:

```
app.directive('hcPieChart', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'E',
                    template: '<div></div>',
                    scope: {
                        title: '@',
                        data: '='
                    },
                    link: function (scope, element) {
                        Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
                            chart: {
                                type: 'pie'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: scope.title
                            },
                            plotOptions: {
                                pie: {
                                    allowPointSelect: true,
                                    cursor: 'pointer',
                                    dataLabels: {
                                        enabled: true,
                                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            series: [{
                                data: scope.data
                            }]
                        });
                    }
                };
            })

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

   $http({
              method: 'Get',
              url: 'http://localhost:2195/api/charts',    
          }).success(function(data, status , header, config) {

                // Sample data for pie chart   
                        $scope.pieData = [
                        {
                            name: "Sent SMSs",
                            selected: true,
                            y:  data[0].sentSMS
                        }, 
                        {
                            name: "Not Sent",
                            y: data[0].notSentSMS,
                            sliced: true,

                        }, 
                        {
                            name: "Delivered",
                            y: data[0].deliveredSMS
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Not Delivered",
                            y: data[0].notDeliveredSMS,

                            selected: false
                        }
                    ];          
          }                         

}); // End of Controller
```

Here is the [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/tvkoyash/3/) (It will not work, because of the service link).

Anyone could help please.

Comment: I believe the new `$http` syntax is `$http.get('url', {config}).then(function(success){}, function(error){})`

Comment: Have you tried using `$scope.$apply()`?

Comment: @trichetriche, The same issue. UI is not updated by the pieData from the scope. The value is read successfully from the service and set on scope piedata. But I don't know why it doesn't updste the chrt in the UI??

Comment: Don't you have a `refresh` method ? I have never used that component before, so I can't really help you unless it's purely angular related :/

Comment: The scope variable is updated I used to console.log $scope and pidata inside the succes and they are jpdated .But it doesn't update the UI.

Comment: Your issue is probably that the directive is compiled before $scope.pieData is set. Are you passing in $scope.pieData to the <hc-pie-chart data="pieData"> directive?

Comment: @JimmyBob This makes sense. But I don't understand how to pass the $scope.pieData to the directive. What I did is like what is shown in the fiddle. So is there anything missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jimmy is right, your problem is the chart renders and after that the success function get the response

to prevent that you have to create flag and use ng-if, so the html will be like that

```
<hc-pie-chart  ng-if="flag" data = "pieData" title="Manual Campaigns" >Placeholder for Manual Campaigns pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
```

and the JS will be like that:-

```
$scope.flag = false;   

          $http.get("http://localhost:2195/api/charts")
              .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);                  

                  $scope.pieData = [
                        {
                            name: "Sent SMSs",
                            selected: true,                            
                            y : response.data[0].sentSMS

                        }, 
                        {
                            name: "Not Sent",
                            y: response.data[0].notSentSMS,
                            sliced: true,

                        }, 
                        {
                            name: "Delivered",
                            y:response.data[0].delivered
                        },
                        {
                            name: "Not Delivered",
                            y: response.data[0].notDelivered,

                            selected: false
                        }
                    ]

                    console.log($scope.pieData);
                    $scope.flag = true;  //set the flag equal true to show it

              });
```

Comment: I don't think this will work because `scope.data` isn't available in the link function even when the component is wrapped in ngIf.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "scope.data isn't available in the link function" which link and which function

Comment: The `hcPieChart` directive, has a `link` function defined. When we try to do `series: [{ data: scope.data }]` it doesn't work. `scope.data` is undefined. I'm not sure why, but it's certainly the case in angular 1.1.0.

Comment: This worked fine and solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited your fiddle like so:

**Controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  //Should live in service;
  var getData = function() {
    return $http.get('http://localhost:2195/api/charts')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
      });
  };

  getData().then(function(data) {

    $scope.pieData = [{
      name: "Sent SMSs",
      selected: true,
      y: response.data[0].autoSent

    }, {
      name: "Not Sent",
      y: response.data[0].notSent,
      sliced: true,

    }, {
      name: "Delivered",
      y: response.data[0].delivered
    }, {
      name: "Not Delivered",
      y: response.data[0].notDelivered,

      selected: false
    }];    

  });

}); // End of Controller
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('hcPieChart', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div></div>',
    scope: {
      title: '@',
      data: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      //Using a watch ensures that we can always access
      // data in the link function
      scope.$watch('data', function(newValue) {
        Highcharts.chart(element[0], {
          chart: {
            type: 'pie'
          },
          title: {
            text: scope.title
          },
          plotOptions: {
            pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
              }
            }
          },
          series: [{
            data: newValue
          }]
        });
      });
    }
  };
})
```

**Template**

```
<div class="row" ng-if="pieData">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <hc-pie-chart title="Manual Campaigns" data="pieData">Placeholder for Manual Campaigns pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <hc-pie-chart title="Auto Campaigns">Placeholder for Auto Campaigns pie chart</hc-pie-chart>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note that a lot of this goes against best practices. Angular has moved on a lot since 1.1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to AngularJS, can you guide me what is the best practices for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Sure, can you provide what `http://localhost:2195/api/charts` returns and I can put an example together for you?